# How an object of one class with the reference variable of another class in java gets created?

Tags: java, oop, overriding

This works fine

```
class A 
{
    public void f1(int x) {
        System.out.println("F1 of A");
    }   
}

class B extends A
{
    public void f1(int x) {
        System.out.println("F1 of B");
    }
}

public class Overriding {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        A obj = new B(); //No Error
        obj.f1(7);
    }
}
```

But this gives an error

```
class A
{
    public void f1(int x) {
        System.out.println("F1 of A");
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public void f1(int x) {
        System.out.println("F1 of B");
    }
}

public class Overriding {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        B obj1 = new A(); // error: incompatible types: A cannot be converted to B
        obj1.f1(7);
    }
}
```

What is the concept of creating an object of one class and referencing it with the reference variable of other class in java?

Comment: That's pretty basic OOM here. In both cases `B` is-a `A`, but the opposite is not necessarily true, e.g. there might be other objects that inherit from `A` but aren't `B`s. Therefore you can assign a child class instance with the reference of its parent class or interface(s) but not the other way around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a new class that inherits the fields and methods of another class, the object you make needs to be the type of the parent class.

If you have a class `Shape` and another class that `extends` it, say, `Circle`:

You can create a `Shape` of type `Circle`, but you cannot create a `Circle` of type `Shape`. `Shape` is not guaranteed to have functions and fields for radius, circumference, diameter, etc...

Oracle has some very useful tutorials on inheritance I suggest you read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Nice explanation BTW - I upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Think about it this way: all Kia Souls are cars, but not all cars are Kia Souls. I can assume that Kia Souls have all properties that are common to all cars, but I know for a fact that cars in general don't have all of the same properties as Kia Souls.

You can do something like

```
Car car = new KiaSoul();
```

but you specifically **cannot** do something like

```
KiaSoul soul = new Car();
```